# Spree missing template issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have been using spree for quite some time and I have encountered the
strangest thing. All of a sudden on my local enviorment when I get
into the check out flow I get the following error message.

Template is missing

```
Missing template checkout/update with
{:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}
in view paths "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/local_store/app/
views", "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/local_store/vendor/
plugins/dynamic_form/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/
local_store/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/drturk/
spree_paypal_express/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/
local_store/spree_essential_blog/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/Work/
WebWork/ror/local_store/spree_essential_cms/app/views", "/Users/
koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/local_store/spree_essentials/app/views",
"/Users/koolkrasher/Work/WebWork/ror/drturk/spree-subscriptions/app/
views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/
spree-0.60.1/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/
gems/spree_sample-0.60.1/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/
ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_promo-0.60.1/app/views", "/Users/
koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_dash-0.60.1/app/
views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/
spree_api-0.60.1/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-
p290/gems/spree_auth-0.60.1/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/
ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.3.3/app/views", "/Users/koolkrasher/.rvm/
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.60.1/app/views"
```

I havent changed anything in any of the controllers or removed any
views. Most recent change i have made was to add a conversion pixel
and im pretty sure that wouldn't cause this issue.
Has anyone encountered this before? If so How should I go about
attacking this problem?
spree 0.60.1
ruby 1.9.2
rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract your gem from any group, and re-rub bundle install.